# How to prove H is a subgroup of G if G is abelian and H is all members of G whose order is finite?

Tags: abstract-algebra

G is an abelian group.  H is all members of G such that o(g) = k (finite k belonging to natural number set).  Assuming that H subset of G is proven, could I automatically assume that x, y belonging to H implies xy belong to H?

How do I show if xy belong to H, x inverse also belongs to H?

THANKS!

Comment: You need first to prove that $xy$ has finite order when both factors do. This will be easy because $G$ is abelian so nice laws of exponents hold.  Carry on.

Comment: Also, you should carefully state the problem, because as stated it is not true.  Elements of a FIXED order $k$ will not form a subgroup (for one, it will not contain the identity if $k > 1$).  My guess is your problem is to show the set of all elements of finite order is a subgroup, because that's actually true (it's called the torsion subgroup).

Comment: Good point, @Randall.  I didn't even read it that way.

Comment: @john Did you actually mean you are considering the set of elements of order $k$ for a fixed $k$, or do you mean "all elements with finite order."

Comment: Your title and your body are different.  The answer to you title is "Yes".  The answer to your body is "No".  If o(a) = o(b) = k then o(ab) need not be k and o(e) = 1, not k. However if o(a)=m, o(b)=n then o(ab) <= mn and o(e)=1 and o(-a) = o(a).

Comment: You don't have to "prove" $H$ is a subset: you've defined it that way. You can't "automatically assume" half of the conclusion of your claim without justification, no.

Comment: Makes SENSE!  THANKS!

Comment: FIGURED IT OUT!  If a belongs to H and o(a) = m, and b belongs to H and o(b) = n, ab will belong to H b/c it will have finite order (raising ab to mn results in e * e = e so order of ab is finite and therefore, belongs to H).

Similarly, one can prove a inverse belongs to H if a belongs to H, i.e., has a finite order.

Answer (score 1):

No.  If $k > 1$ then $o(e) =1$ so $e \not \in H$.

Also if $o(a) = k=nm$, a composite number, then if $b = a^n$ we have $b^m = a^{nm} =e$ so $o(b) \le m < k$ so $a^n \not \in H$.  So $H$ is not closed.

(On the other hand, if $x \in H$ then $x^{-1} \in H$ is easy to show.  But it's not enough to make something a group.)

....

But if $k =1$ then $H= \{e,*\}$ which is a trivial group.

.....

And if $H = \{a \in G|o(a) \text{ is finite}\}$ then yes, $H$ is a subgroup:

To start with:

1) $o(a) = o(a^{-1})$ so every element has an inverse. (Because $(a^{-1})^m*a^m = e$ and so $(a^m)^{-1} = (a^{-1})^m$ so $a^k = e \iff (a^{-1})^k = e$.)

2) $o(e) = 1$ so $e \in H$.

and 3) if $o(a)= k; o(b)=m$ then $(ab)^{km} = (a^k)^m(b^m)^k = e^ke^m = e$ so $o(ab) \le km$ so $ab \in H$ so $H$ is closed.

And that's all you need (associativity) is inherited.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Let's denote the order of an element $x$ as $o(x)$ and set $r=\operatorname{lcm}\bigl(o(x), o(y)\bigr)$. Prove $\;(xy)^r=1$.

You can prove  more: $\;o(xy)=\operatorname{lcm}\bigl(o(x), o(y)\bigr)$.

It may be helpful to remember that for any $k$, $\;o(x^k)=\dfrac{o(x)}{\gcd(o(x),k)}$.